# How to handle Mypy when many possible types but expecting a specific type?

Tags: python, mypy

Say I have a generic function that can return a number of different types depending on what properties I select:

```
def json_parser(json_data: Dict[str, Any], property_tree: List[str]
                ) -> Union[Dict[str, Any], List[str], str, None]:
    ....
```

I then call this generic function with specific properties that I know will return a string.

```
def get_language(self, metadata_json: Dict[str, Any]) -> str:
    return json_parser(metadata_json, ["volumeInfo", "language"])
```

I get the following error when running Mypy.

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "Union[Dict[str, Any], List[str], str, None]", expected "List[str]")  [return-value]
```

From my understanding, this is because Mypy doesn't know to expect a string. What is the best way of handling this?

Comment: JSON data is shit. You need to convert that to some well defined structure and verify types while doing so. One way to do that is to use Pydantic.

Comment: [typing.cast()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) can be used to explicitly tell the type checker that a value has a certain type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got two options, depending on how careful you want to be.

First, [`typing.cast`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.cast) is a function that takes a type and a value and... magically makes the value have that type. At runtime it's defined as

```
def cast(ty, value):
  return value
```

but type-checkers are instructed to treat it as some magic black box. You could write

```
from typing import cast

...

return cast(str, json_parser(metadata_json, ["volumeInfo", "language"]))
```

and your type checker will simply accept the reality that the value is a `str`. **This is not checked at runtime**. If you made a mistake and that turned out to be a dictionary or something else, `cast` will let it pass, and your beautiful statically-typed code will fail with a type error at runtime.

That leads us to our second option: assertions. Mypy and other type checkers understand assertions, if statements, and other constructs, and they also understand `isinstance`. So if you can convince Mypy that you've done your due diligence, it will accept your type outright.

```
result = json_parser(metadata_json, ["volumeInfo", "language"])
assert isinstance(result, str)
return result # Accepted as str by mypy
```

or

```
result = json_parser(metadata_json, ["volumeInfo", "language"])
if isinstance(result, str):
  return result # Accepted as str by mypy
else:
  raise SomeSpecificError(...)
```

This is checked at runtime. If someone hands you bad data or you made a mistake, you'll get a runtime error, which is better than nothing.

Comment: A third option is to have your function declared as returning `Any`. This is about as unsafe as cast, but can be convenient!